# Coloring Histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to plot the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame( a = abs(rnorm(1000,17,10)),
b = a)

my_data$col = as.factor(ifelse(my_data$a > 17, "red", "blue"))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

[image]

But for some reason, when I try to add colors, I get the following error:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, color = my_data$col)

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (59): colour
```

Can someone please show me how to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `cut` with  `scale_fill_manual`.

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- data.frame(a = abs(rnorm(1000,17,10)))
my_data$col = cut(my_data$a, c(-Inf, 17, Inf))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x=a, fill = col)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = levels(my_data$col), values = c('blue', 'red'))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to apply your logic in this question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503597/graph-not-changing-colors-in-r thank you so much!